# Filter response from "git diff" command to get only the difference in Shell - Dynamic Solution

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-diff

I am trying automate a redundant deployment process in my project. In order to achieve that I am trying to get the difference between two branches using "git diff" -- Someway and I am able to achieve that using the following command.

```
git diff <BRANCH_NAME1> -- common_folder_name/ <BRANCH_NAME2> -- common_folder_name/ > toStoreResponse.txt`
```

Now the response that I get, looks something like below:

> diff --git a/cmc-database/common/readme.txt b/cmc-database/common/readme.txt
>
> index 7820f3d..5a0e484 100644
>
> --- a/cmc-database/common/readme.txt
>
> +++ b/cmc-database/common/readme.txt
>
> @@ -1 +1,5 @@
>
> -This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> \ No newline at end of file
>
> +This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +TEST STTESA
>
> \ No newline at end of file

So here in the above response only line/text that is a new line or the difference between the two branches is `TEST STTESA` and I want to store only that much of text in some different text file using shell / git way.

i.e a file named `readme.txt` which will only contain `TEST STTESA` content.

**Work around Solution**:

I have found a workaround to filter the response - but however it is not 100% what I am looking for. Command looks like below:

```
git diff <Branch_Name1> -- common-directory/ <Branch_Name2> -- common-directory/ | grep -v common-directory | grep -v index | grep -v @ | grep -v \\
```

The above command returns below response:

> -This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +TEST STTESA

But I want to be able to store only the difference which is `TEST STTESA`

Comment: The difference is actually not just `TEST_STTESA`. The Branch_Name1 file's last line had a character appended - a newline character. It changed from

`This folder contains common database scripts.` to


`This folder contains common database scripts.\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can easily realize, your solution won't work every time. The `grep -v` parts make it unportable.

Here is a "step0" solution : You want to match lines that start with a "+" or a "-" and then neither a "+" nor a "-". Use `grep` for that !

```
git diff ... | grep  "^+[^+]\|^-[^-]"
```

Some explanation :
First, the `\|` part in the middle is an "or" statement. 
Then, each side starts with a `^` which refers to the beginning of the line. And finally, after the first character, we want to reject some characters, using the `[^...]` syntax.

The line above translates to English as "Run the diff, and find all the lines that either start with a `+`, followed by something that is not a `+`, OR start with a `-`, followed by something that is not a `-`.

This will not work properly if you remove a line that started with a `-`. Nor if you add a line that starts with a `+`. 
For such scenarii, I would tinkle with `git diff --color` and grep some `[32m` for the fun.

Comment: Your solution is really cool and thanks for details explanation but I have some concerns that using your way I will be able to get response as below:

**-This folder contains common database scripts.**
**+This folder contains common database scripts.**
**+TEST STTESA**

BUT
I want to have only the difference/new part i.e. _**TEST STTESA**_

Comment: Let's put aside the fact that the lines are *indeed* different, because they don't have the same characters.

Let's go slowly here. We have two lines that we want to remove, but they aren't the same (one has a `+`, the other a `-`. We first need to ditch them.

Then, we can use `awk` to check if a line is the same as the previous one. I don't have enough space here to explain, but if you have written some code, you'll get it.
 

`git diff ... | grep  "^+[^+]\|^-[^-]" | sed -e 's/^[+-]//g' |  awk 'BEGIN{b=1} {if(b){b=0; p=$0} else {if($0!=p){print $0}; p=$0}}'`

Answer (score 1):

--diff-filter=[ACDMRTUXB*]

Select only files that are

- A Added
- C Copied
- D Deleted
- M Modified
- R Renamed
- T have their type (mode) changed
- U Unmerged
- X Unknown
- B have had their pairing Broken
- and  * All-or-none